# Terminal: running processes interpretation

Tags: command-line, process

I have written a program in the Eclipse environment. First I execute it from Eclipse.  After that from the terminal window I view the list of my processes. Now I execute that program from command line and view the list of processes.

I see the process is listed with different states: when the program is executed from Eclipse the state is S, when the program is executed from the terminal, the state is S+.

What is the reason?

Comment: For example the same running process is in different states

Comment: Please provide example output.

Comment: For example when the program is executed from Eclipse the state is S, when the program is executed from terminal, the state is S+.

Comment: I mean the process state

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the process in a terminal, its process state is marked with a **+** because it is the foreground process in that terminal. This means, among other things, that the terminal can be used to control the process. For instance, pressing `Ctrl-C` will result in an `SIGINT` signal being sent to the process. Depending on the signal handlers in the program, this will usually terminate the process. Also, closing the terminal will send a a `SIGHUP*` signal to the process.

When you run the process from Eclipse, the **+** is not there because the process is not in the foreground process group of any terminal. In fact, unless you have started Eclipse from a terminal (and not backgrounded it with `&` or `^Z`), Eclipse itself will not have a controlling terminal, and so will none of its child processes.

---

*) HUP for "hang up", from the days when terminals were physical machines that connected to computers over serial dial-up lines